# Scala Regex Unclosed character error

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to define this regex to detect the  tag in my xml file

I have written the following code:

```
val regex = """<!DOCTYPE[^>[]*(\[[^]]*\])?>""".r
```

but it gives me the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 27
<!DOCTYPE[^>[]*(\[[^]]*\])?>
                           ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE[^>[]*(\[[^]]*\])?>
            ↑       ↑
```

You should escape the `]` and `[` inside the sets:

```
<!DOCTYPE[^>\[]*(\[[^\]]*\])?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `]`, `[` present inside the character class.

```
val regex = """<!DOCTYPE[^>\[]*(\[[^\]]*\])?>""".r
```